# Why is the button not redirecting?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="../includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">   
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input type="button" 
                           value="Sign in" 
                           class="btn btn-primary" 
                           action="../includes/process_login.php"/> 
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Hello all, I have been following a tutorial and stumbled upon this error. Whenever I try to click the Sign-in button, it doesn't re-direct me. It is supposed to log me in.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A action in a button does nothing. The action in the form tag is where the data is posted to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "action" from input and change its type to "submit".

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

This will submit the form to "../includes/process_login.php".

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for  button(submit) is as follows

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Thus, your button should be changed as

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

On clicking this submit button, the form is submitted to the page apecified in the attribute `action` of the `<form>`

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_forms.asp)

Comment: If this helped you, could you please give my answer an upvote.